# Adding the contents of a simple array

Tags: c++, arrays, sum

I am a total newcomer to the world of C++, and not much more experienced in any other languages, so please forgive me for the bad syntax and indentation etc etc...

Can someone please explain to me why this simple program will print the array values that I input, but won't add up the array values?

```
#include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

int main(){

  int alpha[8];
  int sum=0;

 for(int x=0; x<8; x++){
    cin>>alpha[x];
  }
 for(int x=0; x<8; x++){
    cout<<alpha[x];
  sum += alpha[x];
  return sum;

  }
  cout<<sum;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your 2nd `for` statement, you have a `return`.  The code reaches the `return` and exits your program.

You may want to move code to a function to keep the `return` or remove it.

BTW, you can find this out by using a debugger.

Comment: Aye, tried debugging it, but it didn't offer much of an explanation as to why the program didnt work, it just said that there was an error in the active configuration of the program

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**
Thanks for the help, I have modified my code and made it into this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
    {
    int alpha[8];
    int sum = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x<8; x++)
    {
        cin >> alpha[x];
    }
    for (int x = 0; x<8; x++)
    {
        cout << alpha[x];
    } 
    for (int x = 0; x<8; x++) 
    {
        sum = sum + alpha[x];
    }
    cout << sum;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

having tried your suggestions, I couldn't make it work initially, so I fiddled with the formatting. The program seems to work now. I would assume that there was something wrong with either my formatting post-"return" removal, or there was something procedurally wrong with the Eclipse/MinGW setup I had. I seem to have more success with Visual Studio.